# Ie11 data-toggle not disabling

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

So I have an interesting bug that my brain can't figure out.

In the app I am working on there are several bootstrap toggle buttons that have the ability to be disabled. However, it seems in internet exploder the disabled="disabled" property is not being adhered to.

The red x appears over the button and it is greyed out, but when clicked it still changes the state.

An example of the code in a jsbin
https://jsbin.com/koqapejome/1/edit?html,css,output

My html buttons look like this. Notice I am taking advantage of bootstrap 3's data-toggle

```
<div class="btn-group toggle" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
  <button disabled="disabled" type="button" data-label="Something here" data-type="CHECKBOX" data-name="name" name="name" id="form_154_emailList" class="btn yes active">Yes</button>
  <button disabled="disabled" type="button" class="btn no">No</button>
</div>
```

Is there a reason why the disabled is not fully working in ie? Is this a known issue? I could only find vague posts about switching it to disabled="true" which did not work either.

Through testing I can see an 'active' class being added when clicked, however when trying to add a click handler to disable the click it is not recognized when clicked. So it seems to be something else adding that...but I can't figure out what.

Does anyone know what could be causing this? Is it the bootstrap click that is ignoring the disable?

Comment: Yep, looks like this is a known issue in Boostrap 3 - see comments at https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/21237 . Looks like they fixed it in Bootstrap 4, so upgrading could be an option for you?

Comment: @wiiiiilllllll, unfortunately no. Some of the app is using bootstrap2, some bootstrap3 and some bootstrap4 :(

Comment: what version of internet explorer are u using?

Comment: @awesomeguy, ie11

Comment: I just tested on IE11 on my windows computer, it shows the "not allowed" symbol but its still clickable

Comment: @awesomeguy, Yes, that is the issue I am having.

Comment: I tried adding `$(".yes").click(function() {
   $(".yes").removeClass("active");
});
$(".no").click(function() {
   $(".no").removeClass("active");
});` but it only kind of worked. I wasn't able to prevent the No button from being selected

Comment: @awesomeguy In ie11? I was not able to get a click function to trigger in ie11 for disabled buttons. I attempted to try a click function with a return false inside, but since they are still technically disabled the click was not firing.

Comment: oh yeah then remove the `disabled="disabled"`

Comment: @awesomeguy, I need the buttons to be disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code to do not trigger in all browsers:

```
.toggle{
   cursor:no-drop
}

.btn:disabled{
   pointer-events:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with your custom style.
You can check out working version [here](https://jsbin.com/qalajoquni/1/edit).

The problem was with following styles in particular.

```
.btn-group.toggle .btn.yes.active
.btn-group.toggle .btn.no.active
```

They should have been:

```
.btn-group.toggle .btn.yes.active:enabled
.btn-group.toggle .btn.no.active:enabled
```

Or you can apply different style with following styles:

```
.btn-group.toggle .btn.yes.active:enabled
.btn-group.toggle .btn.yes.active:disabled

.btn-group.toggle .btn.no.active:enabled
.btn-group.toggle .btn.no.active:disabled
```